# Transitive scope in maven for provided and runtime

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

According to [maven resolution of transitive scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) ,

If A be our project which have a direct dependency on X whose scope is provided with respect to A.

Maven tells that any dependency (direct or transitive) of X with scope runtime will be resolved to scope `provided` w.r.t A.

Let Y be a direct dependency of X with scope `runtime` w.r.t to X.

`A --> X(scope = provided) --> Y(scope = runtime)`

Now, Y will  resolved to `provided scope` w.r.t to A.

**Observation :** Y will never be needed in `runtime classpath` of A. It will be needed only in `test classpath` of A. In fact , if you take Y as transitive dependency of X keeping its scope as runtime only, still it will never be used in A's `runtime classpath`. It will be used only in `test classpath`.

**Question :** So, should not we say -

If A be our project which have a direct dependency on X whose scope is provided with respect to A , then any dependency (direct or transitive) of X with scope runtime will be resolved to scope `test` w.r.t A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could definitely argue that these dependencies could be better converted to "test" scope instead.

But I doubt there will ever be any change on this.